# Managing dependencies to multiple versions of a library in Java and Eclipse

Tags: java, jar, versioning

In the Eclipse environment I have project A. A has dependencies to projects or libraries B and C. (does not make a difference if they are projects or libraries)
B has dependency on LibX.v1 and C has dependency to LibX.v2. 
During runtime, A will need B.jar and C.jar. Also classes in B.jar will need LibX.v1 and classes in C.jar will need LibX.v2 . 
Being the different versions of the same library, LibX.v1 and LibX.v2 has same classes, so it is possible that a class may be loaded from the wrong version of the library in the runtime, causing lots of trouble. How do I manage these kind of situations?

Kind regards
Seref

Comment: an advice - don't go into OSGi unless you are absolutely certain you can handle it. It is more than just "multiple versions of dependencies"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really, you don't.  Most Java classloaders don't give any guarantees about the order in which libraries will be loaded, so you really need to be sure not to duplicate dependencies on your classpath.  I would check if B or C could be updated to a newer version, or if LibX is fully backward-compatible.

**Edit**: actually, I found something that may help you.  It's called OSGi, and I haven't used it, but it seems like it might do what you're trying to do.  Here is a [link](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2008/jw-03-osgi1.html) to an intro article.

Comment: Indeed OSGI seems to be the only way. This is a very frequent issue if you are working on open source projects. I guess I'll be working on OSGI seriously. Thanks! (actually I was going to update this saying that I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553567/java-classloader-how-to-reference-different-versions-of-a-jar )

Regards
Seref

Comment: The first class found on the classpath will stop JVM from loading any more classes with the same name, can this be seen as a guarantee?

Answer (score 4):

you'll need to use a 'multiple classloader' mechanism (which is what OSGI is capable of). In such a scenario the classloader for class B can only see LibX.v1, while classloader C only sees LibX.v2.
You can it do it with OSGI, but OSGI is much more than this and it's not trivial to get started with.


another plug-in framework is [JPF](http://jpf.sourceforge.net/index.html), which also offers more than just using multiple classloaders. i think they both use the principle of 1 classloader per plug-in (module, whatever, ...)


maybe have a look at [classworlds](http://classworlds.codehaus.org/index.html). I think it's possible to do it with this library. the benefit is that it focuses on the classloading aspect. documentation is not so good. classworlds uses the notion of class realms. take a look at the API Usage example on the site. 
i'll add an example here if i find one.
anyway, no trivial solution for this i think


solving it with dependency management is the best solution of course, but it's not always possible.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the jpf pointer, I'll be checking it out. In this case I do not have much of a choice. I have libraries at hand, with their references to different versions of the same libraries. 
I would appreciate if you could give some insight into what you mean with dependency management. 

Kind regards
Seref

Comment: basically, dependency management allows you to declare (configure) the libraries your project depends on. do a search on 'maven' or 'ivy' for more info.
how do you manage your project and their dependencies, do you have the JAR's stored in the Eclipse projects? also, is there a specific reason why both projects should use a different version of LibX? if not you could solve your problem with Ivy or Maven because it's possible to use only 1 version of LibX and exclude the other one.