# How to manage required, conflicting Java dependencies

Tags: java, dll, classloader, dependency-management, transitive-dependency

Say I *need* (its required) to use `fizz-1.0.jar` and `buzz-2.3.2.jar` in my Java project. Now, `fizz-1.0.jar` depends on `foo-0.1.35.jar`, and `buzz-2.3.2.jar` depends on `foo-4.2.17.jar`.

`foo-0.1.35.jar` contains a `Widget` class like so:

```
public class Widget {
    public int doSomething(int x) {
        return x++;
    }
}
```

`foo-4.2.17.jar` contains a heavily modifed version of `Widget`:

```
public class Widget {
    public Meh makeStuff() {
        return new Meh();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, both `fizz-1.0.jar` and `buzz-2.3.2.jar` make heavy use of both versions of `Widget`.

I can't just blindly add both versions of `foo-x.y.z.jar` to the classpath, because whichever `Widget` gets loaded first will only work for either `fizz-1.0.jar` or `buzz-2.3.2.jar`.

**What are my options here?** Remember I *must* have both `fizz-1.0.jar` and `buzz-2.3.2.jar`, and *must* satisfy all of their transitive dependencies.

Comment: In a nutshell, you are in deep trouble.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553567/java-classloader-how-to-reference-different-versions-of-a-jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you use a framework which distinguishes class loads.
E.g. OSGi framework. Then you can create 2 bundles - one with the fizz implementation and one with the buzz implementation. They both can contain their dependent libraries which do not conflict anymore because they are loaded from 2 different classs loaders.

Example osgi containers or "Eclipse Equinox" and "Apache Felix" but there are more.

Hope that helps.

Comment: if you don't want to use such a container, you can also load the classes on your own using urlclassloader. but this approach is more tricky :-)